# How to upgrade an MSXML Document from version 1 to verison 6?

Tags: domdocument, msxml, msxml6

My application uses MSXML version 1 (MSXML.DOMDocument) to store user documents in XML format.
I want to upgrade to MSXML6 (Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0). The problem is that old documents are not always readable with the new version.

The cause of this is that the old MSXML parser does not correctly encodes non-Latin character as UTF-8, and the new parser refuses to load these document.

My question - how can I read / convert my customers' existing files to be readable in MSXML6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really a good idea to fix those old xml files with correct encoding. In fact, a W3C conformant xml parser is expected to choke when handling this kind of xml files.

As far as I know, MSXML does not provide functionality to fix the encoding for old xml files.

To fix the encoding, you can do it manually with Notepad++ (choose the actual encoding, and then convert to utf-8), or convert programmatically if you are sure of the original encoding, e.g. ANSI in your case. There should be いろいろ sample codes over the internet.